# Rewrite URL for Dynamic Content

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a WordPress site with a plugin that will not let me change the base page URL from http://www.example.com/something/. I want http://www.example.com/something/ to be the homepage (http://www.example.com/) without showing that to the user (e.x. redirecting from http://www.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/events). Any help will be appreciated. The server is Apache, and I do have mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is it for a WordPress multisite? I would recommend [this domain mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/), but did not try it in a while.

Comment: No, this is just a standard WordPress install. I'm not attempting to map a new domain, I'm attempting to mask the URL/rewrite the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ for redirect page on another page or use this plugin Custom Permalinks http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ to custom permalink setting.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I do not want to redirect users. I want to mask the URL. The Custom Permalinks plugin doesn't help me, because this is not a page as defined in the WordPress post editor, it is a page that is created by the plugin.